# After downloading my models rigged from Mixamo they no longer have any materials, is there a way to fix it?

Tags: materials, rigging, import

Mixamo does a decent job when I need to rig something fast but the fact that all material are gone "compensates" the saved time, forcing me to do it again

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531

Comment: thanks =(.................